# Como usar correctamente tr y th en HTML, etc?

Tags: html, asp

Hola chicos tengo una duda , tengo una tabla de tipos de autos con el respectivo ID y Nombre, lo que deseo hacer es agregar un botón de editar al lado de cada campo y que cada vez que haga clic en un boton me rediriga a una pagina tipo_editar dependiendo del id del auto .

Este es mi codigo:

```
<%

 if isArray(listaTipo) then
 Response.Write("<div class='row-fluid sortable'>")
 Response.write("<div class='box span6'>")
 Response.Write("<div class='header'>")
 response.write("<h2><i class=''></i><span class='break'></span>TABLA TIPOS DE AUTOS</h2>")
 Response.Write("<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'><thead><tr><th>ID Auto</th><th>Tipo de Auto</th><th>Accion</th></tr></thead>")
 for i = lbound(listaTipo ,2) to ubound(listaTipo ,2)             
      Response.write ("<tr><td>"& listaTipo(0,i) &"</td><td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td></tr>")
      Response.write("<tr><td ><a class='' href='editar_tipo.asp'><i class=' fa-icon-edit'></i>  </a> </td></tr>")
 next
 Response.Write("</table>")
 Response.write("</div>")
 Response.write("</div>")
 response.write("</div>")

 else
 response.write ("<div class='alert' >")
 response.write ("No existen registros de tipos de autos")
 response.write ("</div>")
 end if

 %>
```

La tabla se me muestra asi y lo que quiero es que el icono que esta debajo del ID se muestre en accion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quieres el botón al lado del texto que esta dentro de la columna tipo de auto ó la quieres en la columna accion?

Comment: en la columna accion

Comment: Abres un fila de más, sólo tienes que abrir un tr por fila: Response.write ("<tr><td>"& listaTipo(0,i) &"</td><td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td>")
      Response.write("<td ><a class='' href='editar_tipo.asp'><i class=' fa-icon-edit'></i>  </a> </td></tr>")
 next

Comment: lo que pasa es que estas creando dos filas por cada registro que recorres, con los tr creas filas, y estas creando el boton de editar en otra fila, tienes que colocar el boton de editar dentro del mismo tr justo al lado de `<td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Y si quitas el `<tr>` de la acción. Algo así en html

```
   <div class='row-fluid sortable'>
     <div class='box span6'>
    <div class='header'>
    <h2><i class=''></i><span class='break'></span>TABLA TIPOS DE AUTOS</h2>
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'><thead><tr><th>ID Auto</th><th>Tipo de Auto</th><th>Accion</th></tr></thead>

         <tr><td>"& listaTipo(0,i) &"</td><td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td><td><a class='' href='#'><i class=' fa-icon-edit'></i></a></td></tr>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class='alert' >
    </div>"
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

El **tr** es un renglón de la tabla, los **td** son columnas, mientras que los **th** también son columnas pero se utilizan para encabezados.

En tu caso se aplicaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Response.write("<tr>")
Response.write("<th>"& listaTipo(0,i) &"</th>")
Response.write("<td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td>")
Response.write("<td><a class='' href='editar_tipo.asp'><i class='fa-icon-edit'></i></a></td>")
Response.write("</tr>")
```